# Apple script - save Korean file name in unicode

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I'm trying to save multiple excel files into .csv files. Also, I want to put the name of each excel file as a cell in each file. The problem is that my file name is in Korean and when I put the name within a file, the letters are broken. A possible solution that I come up with is to convert the Korean file name as unicode but couldn't figure it how. The following is the code that I use. Thanks.

```
set theFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose the folder that contains your Excel files"
tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to (files of theFolder)
set fileCount to count theFiles
repeat with i from 1 to fileCount
set fName to text 1 thru -5 of ((name of item i of theFiles) as text)
if ((name of item i of theFiles) as text) ends with ".xls" then
    set tName to (theFolder as text) & fName & ".csv"
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open (item i of theFiles) as text
        insert into range column 1 of active sheet
        set lastcell to last cell of used range of active sheet
        set value of range ("A1:A" & first row index of lastcell) of active sheet to fName
        save fName in tName as CSV file format
        close active workbook without saving
    end tell
end if
end repeat
```